# How to enter correct amount in Non-US tax return in CSS Profile?

Tags: taxes, financial-statements, scholarship, university

My question is regarding the vagueness of the point underlined in red in the picture below. How can I differentiate what amounts to put in "wages, salaries, commissions and tips" and the amounts from "father's income from **work**" and "mother's income from **work**"?

Is the "wages, salaries, commissions and tips" a *total* of the income from **work** by my parents or is it some other type of amount to be entered?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is that the top is the combined, and the lower are the constituent parts.

I think the CSS profile page is not 100% updated to work with Non-US parents as it is for US parents. For US parents it asks you to list an arbitrary number of parents and their genders. It then asks you for each parent's income individually based on their 1040 tax return.

This is where I got my info from: [CSS profile tutorial video](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/misc/css-profile/css-profile-tutorial/index.html), and [Getting Started With Your CSS Profile](https://cssprofile.collegeboard.org/getting-started-your-css-profile-application).